# Find Sylow subgroups of $G=Aut(\mathbb Z_{276})$ that is the group of automorphism $\mathbb Z_{276} \to \mathbb Z_{276}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

It was in the test. I did:
$Aut(\mathbb Z_{276}) =~ Aut(\mathbb Z_{23}) \times  Aut(\mathbb Z_4) \times Aut(\mathbb Z_3) =~ U(\mathbb Z_{23}) \times U(\mathbb Z_3) \times U(\mathbb Z_4) =~ \mathbb Z_{11} \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ ,

Finding that $5$ is primitive root of $23$, so $U(\mathbb Z_{23})$ is cyclic of order $22$ and so isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{22}$ and so to $\mathbb Z_{11} \times \mathbb Z_2$ because GCD$(11,2)=1$.
The problem was to find a Sylow subgroup of order $2^3$ ($11\times2\times2\times2$ is the order of my group) but I didn't know why I couldn't find it. Help me please.

Comment: i think i did something wrong, cuz the first Silow theorem says that at least one Silow subgroup exists for each p. Of course i did something wrong

Comment: So the subgroup would be the $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$ component of the product, no?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you mean by "find".

As you have noticed,
$$
Aut(\mathbb Z_{276}) \cong U(276) \cong  U(23) \times U(3) \times U(4) \cong \mathbb Z_{11} \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2
$$
Therefore, the $2$-Sylow subgroup of $Aut(\mathbb Z_{276})$ corresponds to $0 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$.

Thus, abstractly, the $2$-Sylow subgroup of $Aut(\mathbb Z_{276})$ is $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$.

If you want to describe this subgroup explicitly in $Aut(\mathbb Z_{276})$, you need to find the automorphisms of $\mathbb Z_{276}$ of order $2$. This can be done by solving $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 276$. Each solution gives an automorphism $x \mapsto ax$. You'll find that $a= \pm 1, \pm 47, \pm 91, \pm 137$.

Alternatively, you can always write down explicitly the three group isomorphisms above.

Comment: im so dumb..i was thinking only about cyclic subgroups, considering class of 0 or 1 module .

Comment: Thank you. So the subgroups is composed by the following elements :  (0,0,0,0),(0,1,1,1),(0,0,0,1),(0,0,1,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,1,0,1),(0,1,1,0)(0,0,1,1)

Comment: which of course are the element of 0xZ2xZ2xZ2